Looking for a Function that Satisfies 3 Conditions
I'm looking for a function $ f(x) $ that satisfies the following conditions:

Product Condition: $$ f(x) \cdot f\left(-\frac{x}{k}\right) = 1 $$ for any given constant $ k > 0 $.
Monotonicity: The function $ f(x) $should be strictly monotonically increasing for all $ x \in \mathbb{R} $.
Positivity: The function $ f(x) > 0 $ for all $ x \in \mathbb{R} $.

I've explored functions like the exponential $ f(x) = e^{x/k} $ but they don't seem to fully satisfy the product condition for arbitrary $ k > 0 $, only for $ k = 1 $. I appreciate any insights or suggestions for constructing a function that meets all three criteria, or whether it is not possible at all to find such a function.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Since you want these properties for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Let's put $x=-a$ and $x=ak$ to see what we get for the first condition.

For $x=-a$, we have $f(-a)f(a/k)=1$
For $x=ak$, we have $f(ak)f(-a)=1$

To satisfy 1 and 2 together, we must have $f(ak)=f(a/k)$ for arbitrary $a$ and $k$. This is true only if $a=0$ or $k=1$ since we want $f$ to be monotonically increasing as well. So such a function does not exist.

Thanks! It's because of the Monotonicity condition that $f(ak) \neq f(a/k)$ for $k\neq1$, right?

@Krampfmeister precisely. A constant function will satisfy this for example. But monotonically increasing forbids it.
